# How can I generate my desired exit code on shell commands or one-line scripts?

Tags: shell, exit-status

I would like to generate some **exit code**, say 20.
But if I do on shell:

```
$ exit 20
```

the shell is closed (X-Windows case) or I am logged out (text console case). Of course, inside .sh scripts, this command works fine.

I have **tested** with no success:

```
$ return 20
bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
$ break 20
bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

Is there any way to **assign a value to `$?`** variable?

Comment: Could you describe why you need this?

Comment: @Kusalananda : I have developed a script that executes some command(s) from a config text file and reacts depending of its exit code and/or output data. Sometimes those command(s) return a useful and known exit code, and sometimes you need to forge this exit code as desired. I preferred not to enlarge the question, but i f you think more details could be useful to understand the problem to solve, I could edit the original question and add some example.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering because it's an uncommon thing to do, and sometimes we get what we call "XY questions" where someone asks about "X" but it's really "Y" that they need help with and "X" might even be a convoluted unnecessary thing to do to solve "Y".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exit in a subshell:

```
(exit 20)
```

Or you can write a function:

```
ret () { return $1; }
ret 20
```

Comment: Working OK. Thanks you, Olorin. Someone expanding on why the `(` `)` trick works would be nice.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Because it's exiting from the subshell and not your current shell.

Comment: As mentioned, a subshell is created by the `( ... )`. `exit` in  the subshell only exist the subshell, not the original shell.